# In NestJS pipes, can the pipe output type be checked against the type of the decorated parameter?

Tags: nestjs

I was reading https://docs.nestjs.com/pipes

Specifically this example:

```
@Get()
async findOne(@Query('id', ParseIntPipe) id: number) {
  return this.catsService.findOne(id);
}
```

Is there a way to write a pipe such that the Typescript compiler would error if `number` was changed to, for example, `boolean` in the above?

To give a concrete example, can I make something like the below have a compile-time error:

```
@Get()
async findOne(@Query('id', ParseIntPipe) id: boolean) {
  return this.catsService.findOne(id);
}
```

Where the error would be something like "`ParseIntPipe returns number but is used here with boolean`"

Comment: TypeScript does not directly support the type of checking you are asking for. Your Pipes will be invoked at runtime, and any errors due to a mismatch between the type declared in your controller and the logic within your Pipe will also occur at runtime, not at compile-time.

Comment: I realize that at runtime anything could happen. At compile time though we know that `ParseIntPipe` is declared as returning `number`. I'll update the question with the erroneous code I hope to catch at compile time.

Answer (score -1):

In NestJS, when you're using a Query parameter, you must declare your pipes and you should define them according to the type you'll be receiving. If you intend to take a boolean parameter, you should use ParseBoolPipe. So, you need to write your endpoint like this:

```
@Get()
async findOne(@Query('id', ParseBoolPipe) id: boolean) {
  return this.catsService.findOne(id);
}
```

Please keep in mind that TypeScript is a statically typed language, but JavaScript, which TypeScript transpiles to, is not. TypeScript can catch type errors at compile-time, but once the code is transpiled to JavaScript and running, it loses the type information. This is why NestJS provides these pipes (like ParseIntPipe and ParseBoolPipe) which not only perform validation but also transformation at runtime.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm afraid this doesn't answer the question. I'm only interested in trying to catch a mismatch of the pipe output type and the parameter type at compile time.

Comment: Many of your answers appear likely to have been entirely or partially written by AI (e.g., ChatGPT). As a heads-up, [posting of AI-generated content is not permitted on Stack Overflow](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). 

If you used an AI tool for assistance on this answer, could I ask you to (1) Reply in a comment here confirming that it was AI-generated, along with what tool (e.g., ChatGPT, Bing Chat, Copilot, etc.) -- We're compiling data on AI-assisted answers and could use your help. (2) After commenting, I recommend deleting your answer.  Thanks!

Comment: **Readers should review this answer carefully and critically, as AI-generated information often contains fundamental errors and misinformation.** If you observe quality issues and/or have reason to believe that this answer was generated by AI, please leave feedback accordingly. The moderation team can use your help to identify quality issues.